# Deploying asp.net 5 application to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to deploy my asp.net 5 mvc application to azure. 
First time I faced this error:

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the
>   template parameter 'sku' at line '16' and column '17' is not valid.'.

Fixed it by creating web app in azure portal instead from visual studio.

Now I have this error:

> Error EPERM, open 'C:\Windows\npm-debug.log'  MapApp  DNU 0

Cant find the solution of this problem , I tried to clean and rebuild my project, reopen visual studio. Also when I launch my app in local mode all is fine (i.e. no errors appears ).

P.S. Full error stack:

> ------ Publish started: Project: MapApp, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>   Environment variables:
>   Path=\Mac\Home\Desktop\Work\DemoApps\MapApp\Server\MapApp\src\MapApp\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\extensions\microsoft\web tools\external;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Parallels Tools\Applications;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\max.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\extensions\microsoft\web tools\external.git
>   C:\Users\max.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5\bin\dnu.cmd publish "\Mac\Home\Desktop\Work\DemoApps\MapApp\Server\MapApp\src\MapApp" --out "C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp" --configuration Release --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5 --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --quiet
>   '\Mac\Home\Desktop\Work\DemoApps\MapApp\Server\MapApp\src\MapApp'
>   CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>   UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
>   Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta5-12103
>   Executing script 'prepublish' in project.json
>   '\Mac\Home\Desktop\Work\DemoApps\MapApp\Server\MapApp\src\MapApp'
>   CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>   UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
>   npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
>
> npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\Windows\package.json'
>
> npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
>
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
>
> npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\\node\node" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
>   Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows
>
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
>
> npm ERR! path C:\Windows\package.json
>
> npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
>
> npm ERR! errno 34
>
> DNU(0,0): Error : EPERM, open 'C:\Windows\npm-debug.log'
>
> npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Windows\npm-debug.log'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', path: 'C:\Windows\npm-debug.log' }
>   npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
>
> npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\\node\node" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>
> npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows
>
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
>
> npm ERR! path C:\Windows\npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! code EPERM
>
> npm ERR! errno 50
>
> DNU(0,0): Error : EPERM, open 'C:\Windows\npm-debug.log'
>
> The 'prepublish' script failed with status code 34.

Comment: I found this in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30709471/5325148

Comment: I fixed this error. Now I have another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Panich, I haven't seen that error myself so it will be hard to reproduce on my end.

I would suggest the following: create a new blank ASP.NET 5 web app, and deploy it to a test site on Azure. Add a few things to it, from your own application and redeploy it a couple of more times to see if it fails after adding any particular item.

Hope that helps you narrow down the issue.

Comment: @PanichMaxim Are you getting any particular error message? Are you deploying via Visual Studio or FTP or GitHub or other method?

Answer (score 0):

I have just started with ASP.NET 5 and tried to create a self-hosted application.
Thereby (by deploy the app to a directory) I also had the error:

```
EPERM, open 'C:\Windows\npm-debug.log'
```

I then have noted, that to deploy a project from a network share seems not to be supported "out-of-the-box" (I think, there are some special settings / configurations to do, to make it work).
Therefore, I have copied the project from the network-share to a **local drive** and then was able to deploy it.
**So.. I would try to copy the project to a local drive...**

Link to my posting to the self-hosting:
[ASP.NET5 self-hosting, change localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893780/how-to-change-server-urls-with-microsoft-aspnet-server-weblistener/33757957#33757957)